# FSharp type Provider -- Different Sheet than first?

Tags: excel, f#, type-providers

Using http://fsprojects.github.io/ExcelProvider/ it would appear that the second argument for the type provider is called 'sheet' but it only allows you to specify a range of cells IN THE FIRST SHEET ONLY.

There are tests in the project with multiple sheets but oddly they never use the other sheets.

What gives?  Can I use this library in a project with multiple sheets?

type StateDB = ExcelFile< "State Definitions.xlsx", "State Sheet">

Comment: I suppose the assumption is that different sheets are likely to have data with a different schema.

Comment: That's fine but I can't even target anything other than the first sheet.  I updated the title.

Comment: Did you try specifying the range with the ! syntax (for example, adapted from http://fsprojects.github.io/ExcelProvider/: `ExcelFile< "MultipleRegions.xlsx", "Sheet2!A1:C5,Sheet2!E3:G5", true>`)?

Comment: That's amazing.  Answer the question and I'll mark it as the answer; otherwise I'll answer it myself in 24 hours.  The documentation is terrible so I'm glad this is now documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently if you specify the range with the `SheetName!CellRange` syntax, you will be able to do what you want.  This example is adapted from the example at http://fsprojects.github.io/ExcelProvider:

```
ExcelFile< "MultipleRegions.xlsx", "Sheet2!A1:C5,Sheet2!E3:G5", true>
```